# Android - create droppable view with list

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

How can I create view in Android that will be working like droppable list with alfa background?
Maybe this graphic will help to understand:
[image: CLICK]

So I have control "MY VIEW" and some layout below it, when I drag "MY VIEW" down list with background alfa will be shown. Which controls/ maybe libraries can I use? 
This is similar in operation to system bar.

@EDIT:
This is what I have tried:
I make xml with RelativeView, on bottom it have button "SCROLL ME":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="SCROLL ME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="New Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Next I add this to activity layout with include:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.android.fragmenttest.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="New Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="New Button" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/fragmentitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="-130dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
        android:text="New Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I this include have -margin value, now I want to drag it, and if I drag whole include height it will be shown on whole screen with alfa background (second view with list will be shown on first view with alfa).

Comment: I tried create LinearLayout with that black button "MY VIEW" on bottom and add it with minus margin but it doesn't work.

Comment: Post your xml code whatever tried.

Answer (score 0):

I used popup window for similar purpose

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: no, popup isn't what I am looking for :) But thanks!